# skype chat with several contacts log

Tags: skype, logging, chat

I had a chat with several persons at once in the skype. Where can I find log for it?

There is not problem if I speak with one person - log is visible, but I was not able to find if somebody else invited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an application like [Skype Log View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/skype_log_view.html)

> Skype Log files are stored under `C:\Documents and Settings\[Profile Name]\Application Data\Skype\[Skype User]`. In Windows Vista and 2008, the log files are stored under `C:\Documents and Settings\[Profile Name]\AppData\Roaming\Skype\[Skype User]`.